# automatically set assembly version to false

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-assembly

The references in my .net projects must have their attribute 'specific version' to false. I use nuget to reference external dll's and for some reason this attribute keeps reseting to true in a random manner.

Is there a way to prevent that ? If not, how would I create a powershell script to set this attribute to false whenever I open my solution ?

Comment: This is a really good question, I have a similar problem - the build server creates different versions to local dev machines - and it is an annoying and seemingly unnecessary way to break the build.

Comment: I ended up creating an add-in to visual studio for batch setting the 'specific version' attribute to false for all projects in the loaded solution. So whenever I spot a reference with this attribute set to true, I run the add-in to make sure they all get set to false. I haven't found a way to do that at startup. And to be honest, that problem seems to be gone anyway, it's been a while since I last had to run the add-in*